# what is beforeAuthUrl and afterAuthUrl in customer module?

Tags: customer, session, redirect, login

Some explain about **beforeAuthUrl** and **afterAuthUrl**.

These two are session variable used in customer module to redirect to last visit page before login. This is my understanding.

> But why magento use these two variable instead of one variable.

Could some one explain about these variables briefly.

I've refer [**this**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/231563/) link but 'm not fully understand that. To get more information about this i've post this question here. 
Thanks to **xyking** for asking this question.

Cheers.

Comment: in your link answer is already there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AfterAuthUrl()`: Set this when you want to redirect user after login to specific URL.

`beforeAuthUrl()`:set this if you want the customer to redirect to particuler page after registration.. including you can also redirect customer to login page so that he/she can do login after registration.

Reason for using this 2 seperate variable is clear in above sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct about `afterAuthUrl`, i.e., it is where the customer is redirected upon logging in. However `beforeAuthUrl` is where the user is redirected if the login attempt fails, e.g., with a wrong password. This is the case for the variables in the 'customer/session' singleton.

Comment: If this is true, then I cant understand why it calls before auth url in _welcomeCustomer in the customer account controller.